Is this strange behavior from Clang a compiler bug?
This code
#include <memory>

consteval auto func1()
{
    return std::make_unique<int>();
}

template <typename T>
consteval auto func2()
{
    [](auto) -> int {
        func1();
        return {};
    }(0);
}

consteval auto func3()
{
    func2<int>();
}

compiles with GCC, but results in the following errors with Clang:
<source>:11:2: error: immediate function 'operator()<int>' used before it is defined
   11 |         [](auto) -> int {
      |         ^
<source>:11:2: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'func2()::(anonymous class)::operator()<int>' requested here
<source>:19:2: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'func2<int>' requested here
   19 |         func2<int>();
      |         ^
<source>:11:2: note: 'operator()<int>' defined here
   11 |         [](auto) -> int {
      |         ^
<source>:12:3: note: 'operator()<int>' is an immediate function because its body contains a call to a consteval function 'func1' and that call is not a constant expression
   12 |                 func1();
      |                 ^~~~~~~

It compiles if any of the following changes are made:

Move the std::make_unique call to func2
Remove the trailing return type (-> int) and return int{} instead
Remove the auto parameter so the lambda's operator() is not a template
Remove template <typename T> so func2 is not a template
Remove consteval from func1
Move func1() to outside the lambda, so the lambda is not an immediate function
Replace consteval with constexpr
Add consteval to the lambda, making it explicitly immediate (thanks to @Fedor)

Given how specific this behavior is, it seems like a compiler bug. Before I report it, however, I would like to make sure: is this code valid in C++23?

As noted by Alan Birtles in the comments, the code also fails on MSVC. In that case, the following changes allow it to compile:

Move the std::make_unique call to func2
Move func1() to outside the lambda, so the lambda is not an immediate function
Replace consteval with constexpr
Add consteval to the lambda, making it explicitly immediate (thanks to @Fedor)


PS: this error showed up in some template-heavy code I wrote, so I spent a few hours trying to find this minimal reproducible example. If someone is able to find a better example, let me know.

Simpler version (without STL):
class Thing
{
public:
    constexpr Thing() : ptr(new int) {}
    constexpr ~Thing() { delete ptr; }

    // Not needed, just following rule of 5
    Thing(const Thing&) = delete;
    Thing(Thing&&) = delete;
    Thing& operator=(const Thing&) = delete;
    Thing& operator=(Thing&&) = delete;

private:
    int* ptr;
};

consteval auto func1()
{
    return Thing();
}

template <typename T>
consteval auto func2()
{
    [](auto) -> int {
        func1();
        return {};
    }(0);
}

consteval auto func3()
{
    func2<int>();
}


I can also replicate the error by returning std::string (this time, MSVC compiles it without errors):
#include <string>

consteval auto func1()
{
    return std::string();
}

template <typename T>
consteval auto func2()
{
    [](auto) -> int {
        func1();
        return {};
    }(0);
}

consteval auto func3()
{
    func2<int>();
}


note that it doesn't compile in MSVC either: https://godbolt.org/z/GzjP8MdWx

off topic. what does '(0)' do after lambda definition? i mean i do not understand syntax at that level.

@user14063792468 invokes the lambda

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr: IMHO up to C++20 ill-formed no diagnosis required (I don't think you can return a std::unique_ptr from a consteval function). I think that it should not work in C++23 (std::unique_ptr still not literal) but the compilers behavior seems different https://godbolt.org/z/f497x574n

@Oersted std::unique_ptr should be constexpr in C++23, so if I understand correctly we should be able to it in a constant-evaluated context (just like you can do with std::string)

Also, the requirement that return values must be a LiteralType was relaxed in C++23.

From cppreference, this seems relevant: "A constexpr function implicitly becomes an immediate function if it is not marked consteval, uses an immediate function in a non-constant manner, and is [...] a call operator of a lambda"

I believe we may need some guidance from a language lawyer, so I added the relevant tag

Writing [](auto) consteval -> int fixes the errors from Clang and MSVC: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nMn8add81

Pretty sure it's just a bug. Try reporting it on the LLVM github.

Clang issue reported: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/117676
